# Is "Thanks to unfriend me" a proper construction in English?

Tags: sentence-construction, complementation, infinitive-vs-gerund

Someone replied me on facebook. "Thanks to unfriend me". I think it should, "Thanks for unfriending me".

Please tell me Is "Thanks to unfriend me" a proper construction in English?

Comment: Your hunch is correct. "Thanks for unfriending me" would be the better way to say it.

Comment: Or "Thanks for having unfriended me", since the action is over already when saying that.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to thank somebody for doing something for you, you usually use the structure thanks + for + -ing form of a verb; you don't use the to-infinitive after thanks. So the right sentence, as you also think, is:

> Thanks for unfriending me.

Answer (score 1):

Your friend could use  "thanks to sb/sth" idiom.

If you look [this](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/thanks-to?q=thanks%20to) idiom up  on a dictionary, you can see that it means

"As a result of ,because of , due to "

When we look at the example sentences :

> It’s thanks to you that he’s in this mess
>
> I ended up walking about a mile out of my way, thanks to following the
>   instructions given
>
> The ​baby is ​awake thanks to you and ​your ​shouting.

Even though it is a  neutral word, we can see it  can be used in a positive and negative way  When it was used in negative way it conveys slightly a sense of blaming someone or something and
 it can be used as if someone has a attitude .

Comment: Can we say, "Thanks to unfriending me"?

Comment: No, Kyle's answer is discussing the other (correct) use of 'thanks to', which cannot be applied directly to your sentence. See Khan's answer for the corrected version of your sentence

Comment: Actually, the way you'd word what you're trying to say at the end of this would be: _Thanks to your unfriending me, I'm quite happy now._ I think you need to include the word _your_ in there. More importantly, it should all be one sentence, since the first part is just an introductory clause, not a full sentence.